# Changing the pdf page size for Springer LaTeX Template

Tags: pdf, templates, paper-size

I am using the Springer template [`svmono`](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/72921/application/zip/svmono.zip) to write my professor's geometry textbook. After compiling in Texmaker, I received a pdf file with page size 21.587cm x 28cm. 
I want to change it into 16cm x 24cm, so what and how can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You set dimensions of your PDF page by `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight`. However, with a standard parameters of `svmono`, text doesn't fit the page. An example of correction by setting `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` is shown.

```
\documentclass{svmono}

\usepackage{lipsum} % A text for an illustration

\pdfpagewidth16cm
\pdfpageheight24cm

\oddsidemargin0cm % correction (PS)
\evensidemargin\oddsidemargin % correction (PS)

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I still have a problem. That is the distance from the top of page to the content in the page is much more bigger than that of the bottom. How can I do? 
Does this help : \topmargin\bottomargin?

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh Yes, `\topmargin-1cm` (the precise value to be chosen) gives a better visual effect. You can change `\textwidth` and `\textheight` if it is desired by your professor.

Comment: Is there a reason _not_ to use `geometry` here?

Comment: @MartinSchröder For some reason the specified Spriger class is used, hence I am trying to make only cosmetic changes.